# MVC routing not working on godaddy but on azure subscription

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, hosting, production, virtual-directory

I have an mvc site deployed at godaddy server. The mvc routing is working fine on my system and i tried to deploy it on my free azure subscription to test. Its working there. My route.config file has nothing new:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

On server, i have a virtual directory named "httpdocs". None of the controller is receiving my call and giving error 404 page not found. Can you please assist as to wat other changes do i need to check as it seems related to deployment on godaddy server. Please feel free to let me know if any other information seems missing here so that i can provide additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After spending almost 2-3 days on it, i finally figured it out. My application is using MVC 5.2 Version and goDaddy provides support for max MVC 5 version. 
So after downgrading MVC FROM 5.2 to 5 version, it worked.

This may help someone else who might face this issue.